# Windows boot loader to boot multiple OS

Tags: boot, grub

How to configure windows boot loader to create options for booting Windows 7 and Fedora 17? I have GRUB2 bootloader installed.

Comment: You already have GRUB, you'll need to rewrite the MBR with windows. The top 2 links here are pretty good: https://www.google.com/search?oq=windows+boot+loader+dual+boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it the easy way, use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). It's very intuitive and easy to use.

Other options:

- GRUB4DOS
- GRUB2Win
- Manually adding GRUB2 entry using command-line tool `bcdedit`

Comment: Any other alternate solutions ?

Comment: I've edited my answer.